# Is an MTU of 1500 indicating incorrect configuration in my home network and/or ISP setup?

Tags: networking, nat, dsl, mtu

I am trying to diagnose spurious UDP connection problems on Windows 10, yet unknown whether rooted in local computer, home network or beyond.

I found log lines, generated by a *AVM FRITZ!Box* brand DSL modem & WLAN-capable router ([relevant doc](https://en.avm.de/service/knowledge-base/dok/FRITZ-Box-7590/1611_What-is-DS-Lite-and-how-does-it-work/)). The text (PoP&ID redacted) translates to "Internet connection established successfully. IPv4 is used over DS Lite." - I emphasized the part I would like to rule out as a source of unreliability during congestion:

> Internetverbindung wurde erfolgreich hergestellt. IPv4 wird über DS-Lite genutzt. AFTR-Gateway: aftr.online.versatel.de, **IPv4-MTU: 1500**, Breitband-PoP: aaa0000aaaa000, LineID: 1UND1.DEU.DTAG.ABCDE.

The connection is made via a phone line (not coax) and the IPv6 MTU is set to 1492. I am assuming that connections to IPv4 addresses happen through packets carrying PPP headers, transported in IPv6 for CGNAT. In that case I would expect additional fragmentation for 1500-byte data units. Is this desirable? Can I run some test to decisively prove that it is or is not?

Comment: Set your MTU to a smaller value, to see if the problems disappear.

Comment: You are probably assuming the following: PPPoE is used (it isn't, IPv4-in-IPv6 tunneling is used) and Ethernet is used (it isn't, DOCSIS is used). Limitations from the PPPoE era no longer apply. New limitations *could* apply.

Comment: Does your ISP actually use PPP? (Also, PPP-over-what? If it's VDSL or Ethernet, then maybe they've increased the underlying L2 MTU to accomodate PPP _and_ 1500-byte packets?)

Comment: @user1686 How would I tell? (maybe the status "DSL" and "256500 kbit/s" helps confirm/rule out specific technology in use?)

Comment: @harrymc I have used the command `netsh interface ipv4 set subinterface 'Ethernet' mtu=576 store=persistent` and, after rebooting, so far did not encounter the problem. Means little, because I have no reliable reproduction method.

Comment: So let's wait for more news. (576 is somewhat small.)

Comment: Ah, sorry, I just noticed I missed you're using a VDSL2 connection in my first comment. So instead of DOCSIS you'll have VDSL2 frames, which is still not Ethernet.